# How do I rearrange terms in this polynomial to take the square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was given the following problem:

$$\sqrt{6ab^2c - 4a^2bc+a^2b^2+4a^2c^2+9b^2c^2-12abc}$$

While I know how to find the square root of a polynomial, I'm not certain as to how I would arrange the terms in this polynomial so that I could obtain the square root. My book doesn't give me enough details as to how I should arrange polynomials so that I can do the division easily. I tried to do this:

$$6ab^2c - 4a^2bc + a^2b^2c^0 + 4a^2b^0c^2 + 9a^0b^2c^2 - 12abc$$

Basically, I put in redundant terms so I could maybe see the bigger picture. However, it didn't give me anything fruitful. 
If anyone can explain how to rearrange the terms in this equation, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so, right after posting this question, I actually figured it out (why do I do this to myself?). Basically, I was overthinking it: I should've just rearranged the problem like this:

$$6ab^2c−4a^2bc+a^2b^2+4a^2c^2+9b^2c^2−12abc^2 = 4a^2c^2-4a^2bc+a^2b^2+6ab^2c-12abc^2+9b^2c^2$$

In essence, I rearranged the problem in descending powers of $a$ and then obtained $2ac - ab - 3bc$ as my result.

Comment: can’t be right as stated: all terms in the square of your answer must be of degree $4$, while under the radical, you have one term of degree $3$.

Comment: You answered a different question than asked. If the $\,\color{red}{-12abc}\,$ was a typo, please fix it in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is $(ab + 3bc - 2ac)^2$?

Comment: It can’t be the polynomial under his radical sign, since your suggestion is homogeneous, but his is not.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, I agree. I think the last term should be $-12abc^2$.

Comment: Yes indeed. Now to wait for OP’s correction.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{6ab^2c - 4a^2bc+a^2b^2+4a^2c^2+9b^2c^2-12abc}=\sqrt { (ab-2ac+3bc)^2 }= | ab-2ac+3bc|$$